# Using AWS API Gateway to build a patch method

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I am using API Gateway to build a patch method.
In then `Integration Request - Mapping Template` i added:

```
{ "id": "$input.params('subscription-id')",
  "env": "$stageVariables['env']",
  "street": $input.json('street'),
  "address_name": $input.json('address_name'),
  "payment_day": $input.json('payment_day'),
 }
```

As a patch http method, the user's API is not required to pass all the parameters.

So if the user doesn't pass, for e.g. payment_day, the field is going to be `''`. The `''` can be a valid value field. So i have two options:

- Put a NULL value on the payment_day field.
- Remove the payment_day from JSON request.

Is it possible to do this on `API Gateway Integration Request -Mapping Template`? Does anyone has a workaround?

Comment: You could just pass the entire JSON body to your Lambda function (using ``$input.json('$')`` and sort it out in the Lambda function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Velocity Conditionals](https://velocity.apache.org/engine/releases/velocity-1.5/user-guide.html#conditionals) to only output optional values if present.

Alternately, as mentioned in comments, you can just pass the entire JSON body using `$input.json('$')` and handle the presence or lack there of inside your Lambda function.